# Apply list over Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, string-concatenation

I need to apply a list to a pandas dataframe by column. The operation to be performed is string concatenation. Being more specific:

Inputs I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']], columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
lt = ['Prod1', 'Prod2', 'Prod3']
```

which results in:

```
>>>df
Col1 Col2 Col3
0    a    b    c
1    d    e    f

>>>lt
['Prod1', 'Prod2', 'Prod3']
```

moreover, the length of lt will **always** be equal to number of columns of df.

What I would like to have is a dataframe of this sort:

```
res = pd.DataFrame([['Prod1a', 'Prod2b', 'Prod3c'], ['Prod1d', 'Prod2e', 'Prod3f']],
               columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])
```

which gives:

```
>>>res
Col1    Col2    Col3
0  Prod1a  Prod2b  Prod3c
1  Prod1d  Prod2e  Prod3f
```

Until now, I've been able to solve the problem looping through rows and columns but I won't give up the idea that there's a more elegant way to solve it (maybe something like apply.

Does anyone has suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `res = lt + df`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform broadcasted string concatenation:

```
lt + df

     Col1    Col2    Col3
0  Prod1a  Prod2b  Prod3c
1  Prod1d  Prod2e  Prod3f
```

---

You can also use numpy's `np.char.add` function.

```
df[:] = np.char.add(lt, df.values.astype(str))
df    
     Col1    Col2    Col3
0  Prod1a  Prod2b  Prod3c
1  Prod1d  Prod2e  Prod3f
```

---

Thirdly, there is the list comprehension option.

```
df[:] = [[i + v for i, v in zip(lt, V)] for V in df.values.tolist()]
df

     Col1    Col2    Col3
0  Prod1a  Prod2b  Prod3c
1  Prod1d  Prod2e  Prod3f
```